# history.createBrowserHistory is not a function - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use `history` library but I got this message:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/history

```
TypeError: (0 , _history.createBrowserHistory) is not a function
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sm_emamian/Desktop/react js/shadyab/app/helpers/history.helper.js:3:30)
```

my helper:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const historyHelper = createBrowserHistory();
```

`package.json`:

```
"history": "^1.17.0",
```

Comment: I got this message: `Can't resolve 'history/createBrowserHistory'`

Comment: `import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'` this doesn't work?

Comment: my code: `import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

export const historyHelper = createHistory();
`  error:`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'history/createBrowserHistory' in '/Users/sm_emamian/Desktop/react js/shadyab/app/helpers'`

Answer (score 3):

1.17.0 version has createHistory not createBrowserHistory
check the link -  https://www.npmjs.com/package/history/v/1.17.0

```
// using an ES6 transpiler, like babel
import { createHistory } from 'history'

// not using an ES6 transpiler
var createHistory = require('history').createHistory
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should replace createHistory => createBrowserHistory  as you can see  below

import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export const history = createBrowserHistory();

Comment: This is correct for later versions of `history`. Which version you need depends on your version of `react-router`, which we don't know from the question.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too,
This code fixes this error

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"
const history = createBrowserHistory ? createBrowserHistory() : []
export default history
```